# Having trouble implementing qsort on an array of integers, not working on arrays with more than 6 numbers

Tags: c, qsort

For an exercise our instructor is having us implement a few sorting methods. Two we build on our own, which I have done fine, and the instructor gave us the code for qsort which looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Your comparison function, here comparing "short" type data.
int larger_than(const void* left, const void* right) {
  short* left_s = (short*) left;
  short* right_s = (short*) right;

  return *left_s > *right_s;
}

int main() {

int item_count = 5;

short* array = calloc(item_count, sizeof(short));


array[0] = 4;

array[1] = 0;

array[2] = 1;

array[3] = 13;

array[4] = 4;


qsort(array, item_count, sizeof(short), larger_than);

//Name of your comparison function --------^


printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4]);


free(array);


return 0;
}
```

So we have to adapt it to sort an array of integers, and also instead of filling in the array manually, the array length is specified in the standard input as well as the integers to fill the array. So my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int larger_than(const void* left, const void* right) {

    int* left_s = (int*) left;

    int* right_s = (int*) right;


    return *left_s > *right_s;
}

void print_array(int* data_array, int array_length) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter != array_length) {
        printf("%d ", data_array[counter]);
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
}

int main() {

    int input_size;
    int data_item;
    scanf("%d", &input_size);
    int* data_array = calloc(input_size, sizeof(int));
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter != input_size) {
        scanf("%d", &data_item);
        data_array[counter] = data_item;
        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    qsort(data_array, input_size, sizeof(int), larger_than);

    print_array(data_array, input_size);

    free(data_array);

    return 0;
}
```

I initially used an online IDE (ideone) and it compiled fine and gave the correct result for the sort. I then compiled with GCC and found it gave me an incorrect sort. So right now I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. For example if I give my program this input:

```
7
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

It returns

```
4 3 2 1 5 6 7
```

Instead of

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I did some more tests and found something very strange, if I give it 6 numbers, it sorts it just fine, however anything more than 6 it gives me a completely incorrect result. I'm quite new to C, so and I've been looking through my code and cannot for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) Warnings are your friends. Enable them and pay heed! 2) Do not use `void *` without need! 3) Don't cast `const` qualifier away. Your code contains a lot of unnecessary and problematic (at best!) "flaws".

Comment: `return *left_s > *right_s;` --> `return (*left_s > *right_s) - (*left_s < *right_s);`  Compare should return -,0,+ not 0,1

Comment: Your instructor's comparison function it utterly wrong and will never work with `qsort`.  The comparison function is not a "greater than" function.  It is a general comparison function that returns < 0 for less than, 0 for equal, and > 0 for greater than.  This is very basic stuff.

Comment: Oh wow... I guess the lesson here is check over everything and don't assume everything given to you is correct. Thank you all. I admit I just assumed it was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom comparison function returns 1 if the first argument is greater; 0 if the two arguments are equal or the second one is greater.

Compare that with what the comparison function is supposed to return (from `man qsort`):

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

If that really came from your professor, you should refer him or her to the manpage.